# Why is "sollte" instead of "soll"?

Tags: usage

I've got the instance doing a lesson on Duolingo:

> Sie sollte nicht alleine gehen.

The sentence translates as `She shouldn't go alone`.

So, why is **sollen** put here in form **sollte**, but not just as **soll**? I didn't find an answer on Duolingo. Any tips will be appreciated..

Updated: I've understood what it is.. It's Präterium!

[image: Pic from konjugator.reverso.net]

Comment: Actually: https://de.duolingo.com/comment/56187

Comment: @Ingmar I've been starting to understand how it does work.. Thank you!

Comment: So if you understood: What is your Question?

Answer (score 3):

No, it's maybe not the simple Präteritum (Hard to judge without further context, though).

You should rather look at this table fragment (note, for "sollen", the only thing that looks different is the heading):

[image]

The form is *Konjunktiv II (Irrealis)*, expresssing something that should/could happen, but doesn't.

Your form (simple präteritum) expresses

> She wasn't allowed to go alone

The Konjunktiv II expresses

> She shouldn't go alone

Both can be valid and both look the same.